# PHP get_object_vars from subclass

Tags: php, class, properties

**Question:**

**How to push `$param` from `load()` to `$data` property in class A?**

Therefor I can use <del>`get_class_vars`</del> `get_object_vars` to load them.

Each time I use load function, it will add $param to $data property.

**Example:**

```
<?php

class Test {
    public function testing($str) { echo $str; }
}

class A {

    public $data = array();

    public function load($param) {
        array_push($this->data, $param); // not adding $param to $data property
        return $param = new $param;
    }

}

class B {

    public $a;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->a = new A();

        var_dump(get_object_vars($this->a)); // showing empty $data property
    }

}

// Usage
$b = new B();
$test = $b->a->load('test');
$test->testing('hello');
```

**Edit:**

used `get_object_vars($this->a)`

Comment: Try `get_object_vars($this->a)` - Class variables are the default (in this case empty) un-instantiated public variables.

Comment: @FDL it is still showing me that `$data` property is **empty**.

Comment: Why is `$data` property empty when I use `array_push($this->data, $param);` when I call load function with `a->load()` ?

Answer (score 2):

`get_class_vars` only shows default public variables. Use `get_object_vars($this->a)` instead; this should work.

Comment: Problem is that `$data` property is still **empty**. Load function is not pushing `$param` to `$data` property.

Comment: Since your calling your var_dump(get_object_vars($this->a)); in the constructor in class B it will allways be empty you need to call it after you have actually called the load function. But what your trying to achieve with this is quite unclear to me.